# Where should I ask questions about architecture of physical spaces?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask a question not about *software* architecture, but physical architecture, i.e., the design of buildings and other elements of the "built environment".

I was looking for a Stack Exchange site to ask what the meaning is of the huge stone symbols on the side of the new Scottish Parliament building.

Comment: As a note, there was an Area51 proposal for Architecture but it closed due to lack of interest. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96809/architecture

Comment: History has an [architecture](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) tag with questions that seem fairly well-aligned to what you're asking about

Answer (score 4):

Your question turned out to be about interpreting some decoration on a building. That is **not** on-topic at engineering. Nevertheless, the engineering aspects of architecture **are** on-topic there.

If you want to ask about the philosophy of art, then you might want the philosophy stack exchange.

I'm not sure if there's any site to ask what a piece of art "means" or is intended to symbolise. Joseph Weissman suggests [the architecture tag on history](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture), but I'm not sure that this would apply, as you're asking about a *contemporary* building.

Comment: The word "means" shouldn't be in quotes because I wasn't asking for speculation about the meaning - it's not like asking for the "meaning" of Moby Dick or the Mona Lisa.    I'm asking about an objective fact - basically what did the architect **say** about those symbols. or what notes about them occurred in the formal approval process?

Answer (score 3):

I've floated a proposal for an [Architecture](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124342/architecture) site.

Please contribute to building it if you're interested.

Comment: As the other answers on this question indicate, an Architecture site has been suggest at least [twice](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96809/architecture) [before](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102395/architecture-home-design) and failed both times. I wouldn't get my hopes up.

Comment: Yeah there seems to be a latent yet not so organised interest

Answer (score 2):

There is no site yet, but there is an Area 51 proposal:

[Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Architecture & Home design](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102395/architecture-home-design?referrer=O-gl6OxAUH3hFc75gWS23g2).

Comment: That proposal was deleted.