# Is there a Stack Exchange site for architecture?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Googling shows me a lot of results for *software* architecture. But I'm looking for the traditional one :-)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture

Comment: [Where should I ask questions about ACTUAL architecture?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281727/where-should-i-ask-questions-about-actual-architecture)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not yet, but there is [an Architecture & Home design proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102395/architecture-home-design) running on Area 51.

Go there and support it! If it gets enough attention and Q/As it might get a site for its own.

Comment: Hello Patrick ; I was sad to read the proposal was deleted ; I no longer use Area51 but I at least encourage other users to support similar proposals in the futures.